# Hot to find rows whose list contains certain string values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find the rows whose list value of a certain column contains certain string values.
For example, the dataframe looks like this:

```
  ID        Name      Addresses
 3920      Chris    [ab192, ei102]
 3029      Jane     [pe019, xi201, de301]
```

I'm trying to locate the entire row whose address column contains this certain address = 'ei102'.
Since the address column is consist of list, I can't use the following code to find the rows.

```
df1 = df[df['Addresses'] =='ei102']
```

How do I get the rows whose address column contains a certain address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Addresses` is a string:

```
df1 = df[df['Addresses'].str.contains('ei102')]
```

If `Addresses` is a list:

```
df1 = df[df['Addresses'].apply(lambda x: 'ei102' in x)]
```